# Conditional WHERE condition SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sum, where-clause

I have a requirement to filter a specific row while doing summation. Table structure and data as below.
[image]

I want to SUM of `[Gain/Lost]` column value for all rows except the row `WHERE [Reason] = 'Order Placed' AND [No Of Month Old] = 1`.

For below case value will be -560.

Comment: You have 3 rows with 'Order Placed' ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Seems like all you need to do is add that WHERE clause?

Comment: Yes. Just want to omit 1st row which satisfy condition.

Comment: can u pl post the desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You described your conditions pretty well in English - now you just need to write the same thing in SQL:

```
SELECT SUM([Gain/Lost]
FROM   mytable
WHERE  NOT ([Reason] = 'Order Placed' AND [No Of Month Old] = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select userid, sum([Gain/Lost])
from tablename
where [Reason] <> 'Order Placed'
   or [No Of Month Old] <> 1
group by userid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT UserID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Reason] = 'Order Placed' AND [No Of Month Old] = 1
                THEN 0
                ELSE [Gain/Lost]
            END)
FROM tt
GROUP BY UserID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM([GAIN/LOST]) as 'Gain/Lost'
FROM YourTable yt
WHERE REASON <> 'Order Placed' AND [No of Month Old] <> 1
GROUP BY UserID
```

Comment: Why HAVING clause without aggregate functions? Use WHERE instead. Also, shouldn't it be `[No of Month Old] <> 1`?